# How can I create Javascript Buttons with Themes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button which is attached to a js action. It currently uses `<a onMouseUp="..."><img...`. The problem is that I want the buttons to be able to change the images depending on the theme (i.e. css file). Since the image is specified in the html itself, this doesnt work. Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: If he images are supposed to be part of the theme, define them in the CSS code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the image in the HTML, you should assign it as a background on the anchor element, as defined in a stylesheet.

```
a.example {
     display:inline-block;
     height:20px;
     width:20px;
     background-image:url(/images/buttonExample.png)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one (assumed I understood your question):

a) Create your images for the states you want:
   a.1 - standard display;
   a.2 - mouse over; (hover)
   a.3 - mouse down; (active)

b) Define the many different buttons in your css:

b.1 - themeCities

```
     .tcButton { width:100px; height:24px;
            background-image: transparent url(theurl) no-repeat top left; }
     .tcButton:hover {
            background-image: transparent url(thehoverurl) no-repeat top lef; }
     .tcButton:active {
            background-image: transparent url(theactiveurl) no-repeat top left; }
```

b.2 - themeNature

```
     .tnButton { width:100px; height:24px;
            background-image: transparent url(theurl) no-repeat top left; }
     .tnButton:hover {
            background-image: transparent url(thehoverurl) no-repeat top lef; }
     .tnButton:active {
            background-image: transparent url(theactiveurl) no-repeat top left; }
```

and so fourth.

You should consider sprites otherwise you are going to end up with an unmanageable amount of images. Another consideration is on the size of the buttons: width and height.

I can help on sprites, ... if needed. There are free websites that manage that for you. I am a control freak and use Adobe Fireworks for all my sprites needs as far as creating the sprite images.

Then, still with the images or sprites in mind, you might want to use a css-ninja suggestion on how to accelerate the images pre-loading:

```
.body:after {
    content: url(image-url-1) url(image-url-2) url(image-url-n);
    display:none;
}
```

Trick on creating sprites:

a) make sure background is transparent and save them either as gif or png32;

b) make sure they are the same sizes for the three states otherwise you are going to have jittery displays;

c) once all the images are done, assemble them in a large transparent background image;

d) space them in that new large transparent image; aligning them top and left;

e) give some space between each image. Some suggest 50 pixels between images side-by-side and top-down. I don't follow that. I just give some space between them.

f) the most difficult task in hard coding sprites: write down it's coordinates in the large transparent image: top, left, width, height.

To use a sprite image you go like this (as one of many variations):

```
 .msSprites { background: transparent url(url-of-the-sprite-image.gif) no-repeat;
     top left; } /* msSprites = my site sprites */
 .tcButton  { background-position: 0 0; width:100px; height: 24px; }
 .tcButtonHover { background-position: 0 -150px; width:100px; height: 24px; }
     /* margin-left at 0px; margin-top:150px ... in the large transparent image */
 .tcButtonActive { background-positon: 0 -300px; width:100px; height: 24px; }
     /* margin-left at 0px; margin-top:150px ... in the large transparent image */

 .tnButton { background-position: -150px 0; width:100px; height:24px; }
     /* margin-left at 150px; margin-top at 0 px .. in the large transparent image */
     ... and so fourth
```

Application:

Regular images:

```
<button class='tcButton' onClick ....>This is fun</button>
```

Sprites:

```
<button class='msSprites tcButton' onClick ...>This is even more fun</button>
```

The sprite, in this case, is formed of the big transparent image and the location of the button you want to use.

I hope I have really confused the heck out of you .... or opened your thinking cap wide open.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh god, now I have to start over XD. I knew there was a better way than having a billion different images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could change the image tags source attribute.

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeButton()"><img src="oldImageSrc.jpg" /></a>
```

Then in the javascript method:

```
function changeButton() {
   $("img", this).attr("src", "newImageSrc.jpg");
}
```